# How does one replace an adjustable back box lug?

Tags: electrical, lighting, switch, screws

Whilst redecorating, we knocked the faceplate of a light switch and realised it was only being held in place by one screw and years of accumulated caulk / paint / etc.

Upon further investigation, we realised that it's not just that one screw is missing, but that the lug for that side has actually snapped off at some point:

[image: Picture of light switch back box, with one lug snapped off]

*Notice that there is a black lug on the left-hand side, but that the corresponding lug on the right is missing. It is just possible in this picture to see the stubby remains of the right-hand lug.*

Because the lug (and remains of a lug) has a bit of vertical movement and on some inexpert Googling, I think these are "adjustable lugs".

So, my question: **Is there a way to replace adjustable lugs in a back box?**

I've tried to find the answer online, but most discussions seem to centre around re-threading lugs, rather than replacing them entirely. I'm really hoping there's a way to do it that doesn't involve excavating the whole back box!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can replace the lugs. They're effectively T-shaped and the cross piece is thicker than the upright so that it can't be pulled out of the slot.

You're going to have to remove the old box completely and replace it with a new one.

The hardest part is going to be knocking the old one out without removing half the wall as it's been well plastered in. First remove any screws on the back. Then taking a reasonably thin cold chisel or old flat bladed screw driver dig into the wall around the box to remove a thin layer of plaster all around. When the box is loose, carefully pull it out.

The new box should fit nicely into the hole and the wall can be made good with a little filler.